# Is it Normal for a Powerful Machine to Stutter? AMD R9 390

Tags: 18.04, gnome, amd-graphics, amd-processor, amdgpu

- Ubuntu 18.04, Gnome
- Ryzen 2700x
- 32GB RAM
- SSD
- AMD R9 390

All of these nice specs, yet I tend to get stuttering scrolling through a large file on GitHub, or watching a full screen video on YouTube.

Is this expected, or does it indicate I have something misconfigured?

Running `suodo radeontop` shows that I am in fact using my graphics card, at least a few % of each metric.

Comment: Read `man mkswap;man swapon;man free`, and do `free -h`.

Comment: ```➜  ~ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31Gi       1.6Gi        27Gi       480Mi       1.8Gi        28Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
➜  ~ 
```

Comment: Please edit your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read, ignored by AskUbuntu's indexing system, and ignored by future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by switching from `radeon` to `amdgpu` kernel modules. The instructions were here:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMDGPU#R9_390_series_poor_performance_and/or_instability

This command outputs what kerenl driver is currently in use:

`lspci -nnk | grep -A3 "\[03..\]:" | grep "Kernel driver in use"`

For me it now reads:

`Kernel driver in use: amdgpu`